# Limiting the scope of a bibliography to an inputted file

Tags: bibliographies, citing, input, multiple-files, scoping

I am in a bit of a pickle. I am compiling a big file with several contributions (over 100-200) by different people. For reasons I won't get into, I am constrained to the following:

- The different files are inputted within a master file using 'input'.
- I cannot really alter the different files inputted (or at least I am trying not to) other than a few lines at the beginning and end.
- Each of the files has its own bibliography with entries written directly into the file (i.e. no bibtex file).
- Some of the library entries in different files use the same name for the library items. I don't want to alter them, but I cannot have the 'cite' commands confusing what they are meant to cite (I am getting such warnings).

For some reason the references contributed by each file are listed from 1 to n, i.e. the next file doesn't start at n+1. This is how I want it to happen but I am not sure why the cite is then getting confused.

I vaguely remember that one can limit the scope of a bibliography to part of a file (I believe wrapping it all within an environment), but I failed to find how to do this. If that is the case, I can put a line at the beginning and end of each file: job done. Is this correct? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Did you have a look at packages chapterbib or bibunits ? If you need further help, please provide us with a minimal (not) wirjing example including a example of input file.

Comment: By the way do you need to stick to \input and not \include ? If yes can you explain why ? To answer to these questions please edit your original post.

Comment: Strange. Sounds to me like you should improve the frontend (quality requirements for submitted files to you) rather then "fixing" chaos ... // Today you have garbage_in-something_out; the better approach would be garbage_in-rejected and quality_in-accepted.

Comment: @MS-SPO There is no chaos, and no, I am not in a position to tell people how they need to submit the files for reasons I won't get into. I am able to come up with those 'human solutions' but they won't work in this instance because I cannot decide how things are sbumitted.

Comment: @jhor I have no particular reason to use input over include. Is there a reason I should change it?

Comment: `\include` is higher level, and can be used with `\includeonly`. But can't be nested and adds an extra `\clearpage` in front of file content. `chapterbib` package works with `\include`.

Comment: I would like to help you but we are terribly lacking information. Are thr various contributions parts  chapters or sections? Do you have  the initial.bib files or only the formatted reference lists? Are these references lists in a thebibliography emvironmemt ? Are you using natbib or any other package that mofify or extend the \cite-ation commands? Can I once again ask you for a minimal example ?